# Regex how to detect character not in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have some subjects which looks like this:

`hu`
`ha`
`ho`
`hi`

My pattern looks like this `#^(h.+)$#`

which is returning all my strings as `true`. This is expected. Now I want to only select strings which do not contain `o`.

**How can I add a negative condition to my regex?**

Comment: What flavor of regex? PHP, JavaScript, Perl?

Comment: Is the slash supposed to be there? `#^(h.+)/$#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `.` with `[^o]`, which matches all characters except `o`.

```
#^(h[^o]+)$#
```

The `[]` denote a character class, and the leading `^` inverts it.

Comment: How could I do this for numbers e.g if my pattern said: #^(h[0-9]+)/$# and I wanted to ignore, for example, "2"

Comment: Then you could list the numbers you do want to match, without inverting: `[013456789]`

Comment: Or in a useless effort to make things overcomplicated use negative lookahead `^(h(?!\d*2\d*)\d+)/$`

Answer (score 1):

You can add negative condition with negative character class

So `[^abcd]` would match any character except `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`

In your case it should be `[^o]`..This would match any character except `o`

Answer (score 1):

To ensure string does not contain `o` character, use negarive lookahead

```
^(?!.*o)
```

So if you want check string if it starts with `h` and do not have an `o` character in, then use

```
^(?!.*o)h
```

Other option is

```
^h[^o]+$
```

where you have to use end of line `$` to ensure that all characters after h are others than `o`.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you need a regex for simple character detection?

```
if (stripos($your_string, 'h') !== false) {
   ... there's an H in the string ...
}
```

would be far more efficient.

Comment: yes, my example oversimplifies what I am actually trying to do, for the sake of explaining simply.